# Getting a list of facebook posts and displaying them manually

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rss

Is it possible to retrieve a list of facebook posts and display them manually, that is, not by including some external element from facebook? I'd like something like an xml or json feed, containing my posts, so that I can display them on my site however I want.

Comment: Facebook's SDK should help with this [see here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed).

Comment: Post as answer so that I may accept it. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed) shows how to use Facebook's SDK to get a user's feed...and then you can do with it as you please!